# SQLAlchemy : eager loading relationships of relationships of relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, eager-loading

I have this structure:

```
class User(DeclarativeBase):
   ...
   teamMemberships = orm.relationship("TeamXREF",backref="user",lazy = "dynamic")


class TeamXREF(DeclarativeBase):
   ...


class Team(DeclarativeBase):
   ...
   name=db.Column(String)
   teamMembers = orm.relationship("TeamXREF",backref="team",lazy = "dynamic")
```

However, I can't manage to write in 1 query (I always end up with loops and multiple queries) that eager loads all these info at once:

- user.teamMemberships
- user.teamMemberships.team
- user.teamMemberships.team.teamMembers
- user.teamMemberships.team.teamMembers.user

Answer (score 7):

You might try just explicitly loading the items in the query rather than hard coding it into your relationships.  Something like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import joinedload
Session.query(User).options(joinedload('teamMemberships').joinedload('team').joinedload('teamMembers').joinedload('user'))
```

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/improve_toc/orm/loading_relationships.html#loading-along-paths